# How may I add `MyClass` to `List<? extends MyClass>`

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, extends

I have a Java Class that contains subitems of Objects that extend MyClass.

```
class MyClass {
List<? extends MyClass> items;
[...]
```

For some reason I can't insert *MyClass* items to this list. I don't Understand why, and how I may bypass this issue. For example:

```
void foo(){
  items = new LinkedList<MyClass>(); // This is OK
  items.add(new MyClass()); // Not allowed... why?
}
```

The compiler says "*The method add(capture#1-of ? extends MyClass) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (MyClass*)"

I really don't understand how to bypass this issue, and why the compiler should accept only a type which necessarely extends *MyClass*.

Note: why am I in the need to use this approach? Because I need to allow extension of MyClass to have list of subitems.

Comment: Why is the first line `Myclass` and not `MyClass`?

Comment: If all you want to do is add instances of any child of MyClass to items, then the `? extends` bit is not really needed: a List<MyClass> will accept any instances that are of type MyClass or any class inherited from MyClass...

Comment: I think the notation `<? extends MyClass>` is read as "some one class that extends MyClass, or MyClass itself" - but there's not enough information in that type for the compiler to know _which_ subtype of MyClass you meant to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `extends` you can only get from the collection. You cannot put into it. You can do that using `super`.

So, in your case, if you use - `List<? super MyClass> items;` you will not get any compilation/runtime error.

Though super allows to both get and put, the return type during getting is `? super T`.

Comment: WOW! That's IT! Every other approach I  tried has its shortcomings:
with `List<? extends MyClass>` I can't add anything.
with `List<MyClass>` I need to cast all the elements on the getter, and I can in fact not use any setter.
This way I just need to cast the elements on get, thus, can write, i.e., 
`List<? super MyClass> _items = getItems();
if (_items == null) _items = new LinkedList<MyClass>();
MyClass item = (MyClass)_items.get(0);`
and also `items.add(new MyClass());` THANKS.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 6):

`List<? extends MyClass> items` means the type parameter is **unknown type** which is assignable to `MyClass`.

For example, it could be a `List` of `MySubClass`:

```
public MySubClass extends MyClass{}

List<? extends MyClass> items = new ArrayList<MySubClass>();
```

Now consider you have `MyAnotherSubClass` which extends from `MyClass` too:

```
public MyAnotherSubClass extends MyClass{}

MyClass item = new MyAnotherSubClass(); // refer it using MyClass
```

Obviously, `List<MySubClass>`  should not be allowed to contain `MyAnotherSubClass`:

```
items.add(item); // compile error
```

Answer (score 4):

The declaration

```
List<? extends MyClass> items;
```

says that `items` is a `List` whose type parameter is not exactly known, but is either `MyClass` or a subclass.

Re-read that, carefully.  It explains why it is not type-safe to add *anything* to such a `List`: its type parameter is *unknown*.  If it happens to be `MySubClass1`, then adding a `MyClass` or a `MySubClass2` is incorrect.  If it happens to be `MySubClass2`, then adding a `MySubClass1` is incorrect.  There is no type at all that can safely be added.

If you want a `List` to which you can add objects of type `MyClass` and also objects of any subclass of `MyClass`, then you probably are looking simply for `List<MyClass>`.

Technically, a `List<? super MyClass>` would also serve that specific purpose, but you would have the opposite problem with that: it would not be type safe to assume the list elements to be any type more specific than `Object`.